# How to add a <meta>-Tag for an Lightning app

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, dom

Is possible to add a `<meta>` tag for my Lightning application?

Within the Salesforce1 mobile application my iPhone turns a custom-formatted date visualization into a hyperlink to create a native calendar entry. As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16465983/ios-turning-my-dates-into-hyperlinks) you can prevent this by adding

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="date=no">
```

to your webpage, but as I don't have access to the generated HTML `<head>`-section directly is there another way defining this within a Lightning Component?

Comment: maybe manually add meta tag with javascript?

Comment: I am not sure if that is "allowed" in terms of security review for managed packages which states: "Components should not modify DOM elements not belonging to the component (neither parents nor children)"  see https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Requirements_Checklist

Answer (score 5):

you can get the response [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/135907/lightning-locker-service-viewport-header/195879#195879)

> Two Options
>
> 1.-
>
> If you are building a Community, You can Add it from
>
> All Communities -> Builder -> Settings -> Advanced -> Edit Head Markup
>
> 2.-
>
> If you are building a Standard Lightning APP, You can Add it from
>   Javascript, but you dont need to use JQuery (I think is your problem).
>
> In a Lightning App you have the following (App Component)

```
> <aura:application template="c:test_empty_template">
> 
>     <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />   <header class="tlf-header">
>     <div class="tlf-header__top"> ...
```

(App Controller)

> 

```
> ({
>             doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
>                 var meta = document.createElement("meta");
>                 meta.setAttribute("name", "format-detection");
>                 meta.setAttribute("content", "date=no");
>                 document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
> 
>     } })
```

And viewport is injected in the application Head
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Update - this answer is about adding `meta` to Visualforce pages, not lightning components as originally asked**

This seems to be a limitiation in Visualforce and Apex. Disclosure: I'm new to VF / Apex but very experienced in HTML. There are Apex-approved ways of adding scripts and stylesheets to the `head` of a document with the `<apex:includeScript />` and `<apex:stylesheet />` tags.

But there's no equivalent for adding `meta` as far as I know.

You can, as a type of hack, insert the `<meta ... >` at the top of the VF page and it may work. I've done a similar quick workaround with the `<meta viewport...>` element for responsive pages on mobile devices, and it works.

However, this is technically invalid markup.

A related answer at https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/5412/27617 has more details about adding `meta`

Comment: FYI, your answer is about Visualforce. This question is about Lightning Components. :-)

Comment: Ah, I see. Missed that. I'm not experienced with lighnitng components yet, wish I could help. Will update answer to clarify