# Lightning Component throwing "Unknown Error: Unable to create locker IIFE" when using a jQuery Static Resource

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, system-error, summer-16

I'm trying to create a simple Lightning Component that is throwing me an Unknown Error of unable to create Locker. My code is this:

> Need a *Summer '16 pre-release* Org to Test & Verify.

**MyTestApp.app**

```
<aura:application>
    <ltng:require scripts="/resource/my_utility/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"
                  styles="/resource/slds_v0110/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-ltng.min.css"
                  afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.performInit}" />

</aura:application>
```

**MyTestAppController.js**

```
({
    performInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log('INIT... ');
    }
})
```

The test result should be Browser Console should show "INIT..." log message, instead it throws a System Alert Dialog with message content:

> Uncaught Error: Unable to create locker IIFE: TypeError: Cannot
>   redefine property: selected throws at
>   https://vc-summ16-3-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/-7CZX427kzYqF5Ue_LxtNg/aura_prod.js:1:27

I know, with Summer' 16 LockerService is enabled, so does this mean, we now cannot use any javascript library in Lightning Component? If Now, then is there any specific way we can access or load jQuery in a my Lightning Component? If I remove following line `scripts="/resource/my_utility/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"` then the Component works fine and the `performInit()` console message is shown in console window.

This above code works perfectly fine in any other org which does not have Summer '16.

---

**EDIT**

Above error is totally dependent on jQuery Library Version I include in my component. I was able to reproduce 3 different errors by simply referencing a different jQuery Library version:

Using **jquery.1.8.3.min.js** - `scripts="/resource/my_utility/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"`:

> Uncaught Error: Unable to create locker IIFE: TypeError: Cannot
>   redefine property: selected throws at
>   https://vc-summ16-3-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/-7CZX427kzYqF5Ue_LxtNg/aura_proddebug.js:13801:7

Using **jquery.1.11.1.min.js** - `scripts="/resource/my_utility/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"`:

> Uncaught Error: Unable to create locker IIFE: Error: Re-setting of
>   sCallback is prohibited throws at
>   https://vc-summ16-3-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/-7CZX427kzYqF5Ue_LxtNg/aura_proddebug.js:13801:7

Using **jquery-2.2.3.min.js** - `scripts="/resource/my_utility/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"`:

> Uncaught Error: Unable to create locker IIFE: TypeError: Cannot
>   redefine property: minlength throws at
>   https://vc-summ16-3-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/-7CZX427kzYqF5Ue_LxtNg/aura_proddebug.js:13801:7

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, using the locker service runs included JS resources in `use-strict` mode. Do you know if your jQuery loads properly outside of Lightning using `use-strict`?

Comment: I've used the same jquery resource in a visualforce page and that page works well, and I then used 'use strict' in that page to confirm if it breaks or not, it continued working well.

Comment: Out of the blue: Do you have a namespace activated? Your code uses the standard namespace. I got the idea since there was a locker update in Summer 16 making namespaces very strict

Comment: No namespace in the org. Should I activate namespace? I'm currently using default `c:` namespace ...

Comment: Please do not namespace the org ,it will affect other components as well .Don't think namespace is the issue here

Comment: Agree with Mohith on namespace if not yet active.

Comment: ok yes, I've not enabled namespace in the org here. Although, I had encountered same kind of issue here in this question - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/119408/issue-with-lightning-locker-service-and-jquery-static-resource - but that question was supposed to resolve the issue in patch .3 of Summer 16, and I have no idea which version my pre-release org is on, I created this org some 7 or 8 days ago. Plus, mine issue is kind of extending into different jQuery versions, I wonder why that may be.